# Hp Deskjet 1510 - Printer Alignment Utility Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: printing

Can anyone guide me? how can i align my hp printer in Ubuntu 16.04. Is there any utility software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HPLIP package should be enough for managing HP printers.
If not installed already you can find and install it from the software center or in terminal `sudo apt install hplip`